# Excel has file big size

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an `.xls` files I open with Excel 2007 every day.  It is approximately 200 rows x 60 columns.

Each day we create a copy of this file, and in the new copy change the numeric value of 20 cells.
No new columns or rows are added, there are no graphics/charts/etc.  There is only one sheet.

10 days ago, the file size was `1.7MB`.  The next day it grew to `3MB`.  The following day `7MB`.
Today the file is `20MB` and working with it is very slow.  It takes approximately 10 minutes to open, 10 minutes to save, and clicking anywhere in the file has a 30 second delay.  Sharing is not enabled on this file.

I'm not sure what the issue could be, any suggestions? I've tried an `Open & Repair` but no luck.  It also doesn't link to an external file, and it doesn't have any VBA code.
Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you save that file under another name (or another format)? IN ye old times this caused excel to dump undo values, reducing the file size to original.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel file with gigantic size](http://superuser.com/questions/437109/excel-file-with-gigantic-size)

Comment: If what you are doing is not much more than storing values, I'd recommend storing this as a .CSV file - this should greatly alleviate the high file size issue and potentially the performance issue as well. edit: Along with being a highly portable and widely used format. It is very limited i.e. only a single worksheet, no text formatting, it's really just storing values.

Comment: I also found that a sheet I was working with, in a similar manner to what you're describing, was creating new Conditional Formatting rules every time we copy/pasted values. Do you have any conditional formatting? May want to check the manager and see if it's creating new rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the overall size of an Excel workbook, you may like to try one/more of these suggestions:
* Don't save as dual format file (Excel 95/97); use the most recent version of Excel you (and your intended) audience will have access to - for instance, "Excel 2002", or "Excel 2000"?  However, save in the oldest copy of MS-Excel you can, then re-save in the latest revision you can.  Doing this may reduce overall size.
* If you notice that the vertical or horizontal scroll-bar(s) go(es) past the end of your data, you can clear the blank rows & columns beyond the extent of your data:
a) Go to the bottom row of data & then select the entire next row by clicking on the row number (in the "margin").  Use [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Down Arrow] to select all the remaining rows in the worksheet, then click the "Edit" / "Clear" menu item to clear the rows of values & formats.
b) Go to the far right column of data & select the entire next column by clicking on the column letter.  Use [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Right Arrow] to select all the remaining columns in the worksheet.  As before, use the "Edit" / "Clear" menu item to clear the columns of values & formats.
Repeat the above steps for each worksheet in your workbook where you can scroll past the end of your data.  Finally, save the workbook, and close it.  Upon re-opening the scroll-bars should now extend only as far as the data.
* Format your cells in continuous ranges (blocks) rather than individually setting the formats of distinct cells.  For example, if all of row 1 is "size 12, arial, bold" do not set A1, B1, C1, D1, E1 (etc) separately, just select row 1 & apply the same style to each cell at once.  Formatting in this manner can also be used with colo[u]rs (cell foreground & background), fonts, font sizes, font styles.  Try to apply the same formatting to single or multiple columns, and/or rows, and make individual cells the exceptions, rather than apply formatting to individual cells one by one.

- Refresh any queries or pivot tables with (select critieria that references) the least amount of data possible.
- Research (via Help) & use inbuilt bespoke functions rather than writing your own code.
- Reduce the length of Range names so that they are still meaningful, but not as verbose.
- If you have any (auto) filtering enabled in your workbook, across one, or more, worksheets, remove this, or reset it back to "(All)" prior to saving.
- Remove any unused worksheets, or any unused VBA code (or pre-recorded macros).
- You may like to try exporting (right-click tab and select "Copy To" 'New Book') all your worksheets into a new workbook & then saving this newly created book as a different filename.  When comparing the two files you may notice a vast difference.
- If you regularly save data across a network (i.e. is the workbook stored on a network), or is it 'Shared'?  If 'Shared', try unsharing & saving locally, re-share & then save back to the network.

Visit this great source for additional information. Maybe will find something useful in that issue.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/35130e9a-4bae-45dd-bdb6-f71e0ac772f4/corrupted-excel-2007-file-assist?forum=excel

Comment: Thank you all for your advice! The issue has been resolved.
 Sorry, that long time did not respond. This is because the issue was solved and I forgot to tell.) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Save as .xlsb to reduce the size , but your probably copying formatting into unused cells as already mentioned in other answers

Answer (score 0):

I'd be willing to bet an entire quarter that there are excess formatting records stored in the excel file.

Verify that there are no unneeded conditional formatting rules. 

Delete all unused rows and columns.

Save the file as *new.xlsx.

Delete the old file.

Rename the new file.

Let us know how it goes.